# Boolean Method Returns Null When Called

Tags: nullpointerexception, return, boolean, abstract-class

Im creating a JavaTraining school simulator for a project for Uni. To do this I am working on a method to simulate a single school day. A requirement this method is to set an instructor to a free course. Each instructor can only teach one course. So for each course, I iterate through all Instructors until I find one that is free. If this Instructor also has the correct credentials to teach the course he is set as the course Instructor. I keep running into a strange problem when trying to place the constraint of an instructor teaching only one course.

I attempted to implement it in the following manner:

```
public void aDayAtSchool() {
    courses.forEach((thisCourse) -> {
        if(!thisCourse.hasInstructor()){
            for(Instructor thisInstructor: instructors){
                if(thisInstructor.isFree() && thisInstructor.canTeach(thisCourse.getSubject())){
                    thisInstructor.assignCourse(thisCourse);
                    thisCourse.setInstructor(thisInstructor);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The Instructors are held in an ArrayList. The Instructor class itself is an abstract class with mostly concrete methods. The subclasses of Instructor are Teacher and Demonstrator.

The Instructor class(codes really messy because ive been fiddling with it trying to solve my problem):

public abstract class Instructor extends Person {

```
private Course assignedCourse;
private boolean isFree;

public Instructor(String Name, char Gender, int Age) {
    super(Name, Gender, Age);
    this.isFree = true;
}

public void assignCourse(Course thisCourse) {
    this.assignedCourse = thisCourse;
    this.isFree = false;
}

public void unassignCourse() {
    this.assignedCourse = null;
    this.isFree = true;
}

public Course getAssignedCourse() {
    return assignedCourse;
}

public abstract boolean canTeach(Subject thisSubject);

public boolean isFree(){
    return isFree;
}
```

}

The Demonstrator class:

public class Demonstrator extends Instructor {

```
public Demonstrator(String Name, char Gender, int Age) {
    super(Name, Gender, Age);
}

@Override
public boolean canTeach(Subject thisSubject) {
    return (thisSubject.getSpecialism() == 2);
}
```

}

The Teacher class has the exact same template as the Demonstrator Class.

I am testing the code as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    School dormers = new School("Dormers");
    Subject basics = new Subject(1, 1, 5);
    Subject Lab1 = new Subject(2, 2, 2);
    Student Peter = new Student("Peter", 'M', 60);
    Student Anabelle = new Student("Anabelle", 'F', 23);
    Course course1 = new Course(basics, 1);
    basics.setDescription("basics");
    Lab1.setDescription("Lab1");
    Course course2 = new Course(Lab1, 2);
    Teacher tom = new Teacher("Tom", 'M', 20);
    Demonstrator jerry = new Demonstrator("Jerry", 'F', 23);
    dormers.add(course2);
    dormers.add(course1);
    dormers.add(tom);
    dormers.add(jerry);
    dormers.add(basics);
    dormers.add(Peter);
    dormers.add(Anabelle);
    dormers.add(Lab1);
    dormers.aDayAtSchool();
    System.out.println(course1.hasInstructor());        
}
```

Initially no instructor is added to course1. I tested this beforehand to make sure that the hasInstructor function is fully functional. It should print true after         dormers.aDayAtSchool(); is called. But it always prints false.

The only problem with the code that i can find is the thisInstructor.isFree() condition. Whats strange is that tried writing this in any way that mimics this functionality yields the same problem. Ive tried many different ways of creating this boolean but everytime the same problem occurs. If i get rid of the condition and use only the canTeach method the rest of the program works perfectly and True is printed to the console as it should. But if i keep it in the if statement the code falls apart. When testing it I modified the condition to:

```
            if(!thisInstructor.isFree() && thisInstructor.canTeach(thisCourse.getSubject())){
```

But the output remained false. This is strange as I had already tested the canTeach function and know it to return true with these inputs. This means that the isFree boolean must be null as it would be otherwise impossible for the output to remain false.

I have been struggling with this one problem over a very simple project for the better part of 4 hours. Any help will be greatly appreciated.